# CMD/BAT file need to leave only 8 characters of the file name

Tags: batch-file, cmd

This is my current code:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set FOLDER_PATH="%rhsZipFolder%\"
for %%f in (%FOLDER_PATH%*.csv) do if %%f neq %~nx0 (
    set "filename=%%~nf"
    ren "%%f" "!filename:~3,-1!%%~xf"
)
```

Now I need some how to leave ONLY last 8 character of the file name, doesn't matter how long it will be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the last 8 characters of a string in batch doing the following:

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set foo=%1
echo last 8 : %foo:~-8%
```

So in your example you would use `!filename:~-8!` if I understand correctly.

Notice the `-` which indicates that it takes the characters from the right side and not frmo the left side.

Usage of my example in the cmd-line:

```
foobat asdfasadfasdf12345678
```

Output:

```
last 8 : 12345678
```